# Lua - Are numbers floats or doubles?

Tags: c, lua, floating-point

The Lua documentation says that Lua represents values of type number using a double, which allows all long integer values to be correctly represented using a floating point number.

However I see in the code that lua_Number is actually a float. Which is giving me the following warning :

```
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'lua_Number', possible loss of data
```

For :

```
double fVarVal = 0.0;
lua_pushnumber( L, fVarVal );
```

So how are the values of type number represented in Lua ? float or double ? If they are using floats, can't this create problems when integer values, like array indexes, are being used ?

I'm using Lua 5.3.2 for Windows CE.

Comment: It is [configurable](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_Number)

Comment: Thanks. Is it worth using doubles instead of floats ? I'm creating very basic things that will mostly use integers, are occasionnally floats without requiring much precision like a physics engine would require.

Comment: I think it depends on your requirements. But I don't think you will notice any performance degradation using `double` instead of `float` most of the times.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm more concerned about unexpected behaviors with floats rather than performance, though that will run on rather weak embedded devices using Windows CE and Android. BUt I guess if the guys who ported Lua to WIndows CE made float a defaultn it should be used as is preferably.

Comment: What unexpected behavior can you get out of using `double` which you won't from `float`?

Comment: That's what they say about lua_Number that made me suspicious about floats : http://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html Though I'm not sure about what kind of problem to expect, if any.

Comment: Floats (instead of doubles) are usually used on devices without FPU.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I've encounterd the exact opposite cases, where FPUs were working for floats but not doubles.

Comment: @Virus721 BTW, why are you working with `double` at all and not with `lua_Number` in the first place?

Comment: A `double` cannot represent all bit of a `long int` with 64 bits (POSIX64).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Well I'm storing some Lua values (primitives only) in my C code to make them available across multipe scripts. Using lua_Number is an option that hasn't come to my mind yet. I may consider doing this. But the values that i'm storing in my C code are likely to be got/set by other things than Lua scripts so I don't know if I should use lua_Numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using Lua 5.3.2 for Windows.

Well that rather changes things. Lua 5.3 added the ability to use actual integers in Lua, directly. Lua always had the `lua_pushinteger` function, but in 5.3, it *doesn't* convert it to a `double`. It is instead a 64-bit integer.

From Lua of course, integers and floats look the same. And most of the Lua C API doesn't make much distinction. But it can if you want it to.

In any case, `lua_Number` defaults to `double`, so even on Lua 5.1/2, integers-as-floats was not much of a problem. Of course, `lua_Integer` and `lua_Number` can be adjusted as you see fit. Just be aware that external DLLs you use have to be recompiled with those settings too.

Comment: "It is instead a 64-bit integer." - it is configurable.  May be 32-bit integers.

Comment: Sorry, i misspelled, i'm using Windows CE, my bad. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: As I said, they "can be adjusted as you see fit."

Comment: @Virus721: I'm not sure what using Windows CE has to do with anything here.